# SQL to Tableau code translation using analytical functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a **price_total** column in SQL that keeps on changing slightly for a column **cohort_month_since** each month. I want it to to be consistent as it was on **cohort_month_since = 0**. I am able to do that by using the below code in SQL. How can I translate this in Tableau?

```
MAX(CASE WHEN cohort_month_since = 0 THEN price_total END) OVER (PARTITION BY month_column)
```

e.g this is what I am getting

```
 month   | cohort_month_since | price_total
Jan 2020 |        0           |  745.09
Jan 2020 |        1           |  745.39
Jan 2020 |        2           |  746.01
Jan 2020 |        3           |  744.99
```

this is what I want

```
 month   | cohort_month_since | price_total
Jan 2020 |        0           |  745.09
Jan 2020 |        1           |  745.09
Jan 2020 |        2           |  745.09
Jan 2020 |        3           |  745.09
```

Comment: Can you please share your work using Tableau Public

Comment: For most (but not all) problems, you'll have better results if you do NOT use custom SQL in Tableau, but instead learn to use Tableau features well, and let it generate (optimized) SQL for you. There are situations where custom SQL is important, say if you are calling a database specific function. SQL analytic queries are sometimes one reason to use custom SQL from Tableau, but I'd first try using Tableau's quick table calc feature. It will be easier and more flexible in most cases, and can usually get a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
{FIXED [Month]: max(if [Cohort month since]=0 then [Price total] END)}
```